# Incorrect string value warning when calling stored procedure in python

Tags: python, mysql, stored-procedures, utf-8, mysql-python

I have a database that has a stored procedure that I call it in my python script.
until yesterday there were no problem with it.
but yesterday my database server had a problem and restored the database.
now I'm getting this warning from the same code:

```
Warning: Incorrect string value: '\xD9\x88\xD8\xB2\xDB\x8C...' for column 'title' at row 1
```

I checked some encodings in DB :
In `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`:

```
+--------------+--------------------+
| COLUMN_NAME  | CHARACTER_SET_NAME |
+--------------+--------------------+
| title        | utf8               |
+--------------+--------------------+
```

Database collation: `latin1_swedish_ci`
Table collation: `utf8_general_ci`
Column collation: `utf8_general_ci`
Server charset: `UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)`
(All are same as before!!)

and I'm connecting using this:

```
self.con=mdb.connect(host=self.host, user=self.user, passwd=self.passwd, db=self.dbname,use_unicode=True, charset="utf8");
```

and variable `title` is unicode.

**I tried:**

- Altering table and re setting `utf8_general_ci` for `title` column
- calling `SET NAMES utf8`  before calling procedure.
- Removing and re-creating stored procedure

None worked!!! :-(

---

I executed an `insert` query on a temporary table with Unicode content and it worked without that warning!!!

---

What is the problem?
how can I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Problem solved!
I added  `CHARACTER SET utf8` to my stored procedure's VARCHAR arguments and problem solved:

```
..., IN `title` VARCHAR(255) CHARSET utf8,...
```

But yet I wonder why before restoring DB there was no problem !!!???

Comment: this is odd ... moved some code to a stored procedure and encountered that encoding issue - even everything was set to UTF8 it seems that we have to provide the encoding in stored procedure parameters as well ...